# How can I modify driver "aggression" in the Road Traffic Library?

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

Im doing a road traffic simulation and have noticed that the vehicles are far too passive. I know for a fact that in the area this simulation is supposed to be the people at the wheel are far more "aggressive" and give less headway and dont yield as much.

I have scoured every piece of official and non official documentation but cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The library is a black box that only "opens" the settings that you can see in the blocks. The only additional settings you can play with (beyond the block properties) is the "Road Network descriptor":
[image]

But there is no aggressiveness setting. If this is the key purpose of your model, you either create your own ABM logic from scratch or you'd need to check other tools that are focused on cars (but typically, these are then far more restrictive on other dimensions that AnyLogic is flexible on, it all depends on your model purpose)

Comment: Oh, so I can’t modify the driver behavior at all?

Comment: as per my reply :) You can modify what can be modified but driver aggressiveness is not among them. Either create your own traffic behavior from scratch (not trivial), exclude aggressiveness from your investigations or choose a different tool (and live with their disadvantages).

Comment: Alright thanks. I’ll do without. It’s for a big school project but the deadline is closing in so I don’t really have time to learn how to do that and also complete the rest of the work. Thanks for the help